# What does "mechanical sympathy" & "transcend crude oversimplifications" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english, british-english

Am going through a [documentation](https://dzone.com/articles/mechanical-sympathy).

In the below quote:

> “You don’t have to be an engineer to be be a racing driver, but you do have to have Mechanical Sympathy.” – Jackie Stewart, racing driver

1. 

What is the meaning of "mechanical sympathy"?

---

In the below statement:

> First, let’s think about why it’s important to transcend crude oversimplifications like “disk I/O is faster than network I/O.”

Dictionary meaning of "transcend" is "to rise above or go beyond", but going beyond crude oversimplications? I don't get the meaning...

2)

What does "transcend crude oversimplifications" mean?

Comment: It means you must understand, and be "in tune" with machinery, even if you don't know it in depth. For example, if you know how a gearbox works, it helps you use it more effectively.

Comment: The second question you added seems unrelated to the first, apart from being in the same document.

Comment: If you mean [this document](https://dzone.com/articles/mechanical-sympathy) please edit the source into the question, and also what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: @WeatherVane I already did add the source.

Comment: If you go beyond a very basic description of something, it means you explain it in depth. The sentence mentions something in a way that can be called a [**sweeping statement**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sweeping-statement-generalization), that ignores the complexity of a situation.

Comment: @WeatherVane *Mechnical sympathy* mean How something works under the hood?

Comment: Not exactly. Put it this way: if you try to tighten a nut and bolt when their threads are crossed, by applying greater force, then you have no mechanical sympathy. OTOH if you know what the screwing action should feel like, you will know something is wrong and avoid breaking it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Your crossed thread example is quite good but I think that Stewart was thinking more of examples like knowing when to change gear or feeling that the car was about to skid. You don't really need to understand how the gearbox, steering or suspension work to have that mechanical sympathy. It could be inherent or you could gain it by experience of driving. Having said that Jackie Stewart's dad was a self-employed car mechanic.